# How can I enable ASLR, DEP and SafeSEH on an exe in codeblocks using mingw?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, aslr, dep

I have tried using `-dynamicbase -pie` and `-e_mainCRTStartup` in linker options for ASLR but when I load it up in ollydbg it always loads at 400000

Comment: That's done by your operating system not when compiling .. If I get you right. Ollydbg is loading on 400000 always maybe because it is the code address and not the stack. if you debug on real time you will see how the stack is randomized each time.

Comment: You do need to opt-in to ASLR on Windows by setting the correct flag on every dynamic library and the executable. A relocation table also needs to be output for the executable, and MinGW doesn't appear to do it without a hack (`--export-all-symbols`).

Answer (score 2):

You can enable DEP with `-Wl,--nxcompat`. You can also pass `--dynamicbase` to the linker in the same way, but sadly it doesn't emit the necessary relocation table. As a workaround, you can pass `-Wl,--dynamicbase,--export-all-symbols`. An explicit `__declspec(dllexport)` of a single symbol like `main` also works, and that is currently the workaround used in the Rust compiler. AFAIK, GCC doesn't implement SEH, so you're not missing anything by missing a compile-time sanity check for it (SafeSEH).

Comment: I recently landed support for high entropy ASLR in the GNU linker via a `--high-entropy-va` switch, but that's not yet in a stable release. It's possible to set those flags on the executable / libraries via the `editbin` utility after they are built as a workaround.